# how to create our own webservice and communicate with chatbot api.ai using java

Tags: java, dialog, dialogflow-es

i tried to create chatbot using api.ai but not able to understand...
how to create web services or API using java in order to communicate with Database

Answer (score 2):

There is a good doc with examples made by the Dialogflow team (ex api.ai) : https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-java-client
Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you give more details, like do you have some error?